# How to get value attribute for corresponding button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
buttonPress = (event) => { console.log(event.props.value)}

  <RaisedButton ref={(button) => { this.RaisedButton = button; }} label="Primary" value = "year" onTouchTap={()=>this.buttonPress( this.RaisedButton )}  primary={true} />
```

When I try to render one button like the above, I get the value. But, when I render multiple buttons, I only get the last button's value for all the buttons. whatever button I click I get `year`.

```
    buttonPress = (event) => { console.log(event.props.value)}

      <RaisedButton ref={(button) => { this.RaisedButton = button; }} label="Primary" value = "day" onTouchTap={()=>this.buttonPress( this.RaisedButton )}  primary={true} />
 <RaisedButton ref={(button) => { this.RaisedButton = button; }} label="Primary" value = "month" onTouchTap={()=>this.buttonPress( this.RaisedButton )}  primary={true} />
 <RaisedButton ref={(button) => { this.RaisedButton = button; }} label="Primary" value = "year" onTouchTap={()=>this.buttonPress( this.RaisedButton )}  primary={true} />
```

How can I get the value for corresponding buttons?

Comment: Arrow functions do not scope 'this'. this.RaisedButton is always ParentComponent.RaisedButton. Not individual references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only keep one reference to a button, and the ref callbacks overwrite each other. Instead, you could **split them up into three separate references**:

```
<RaisedButton ref={(button) => { this.RaisedButtonDay = button; }} label="Primary" value = "day" onTouchTap={()=>this.buttonPress( this.RaisedButtonDay )}  primary={true} />
<RaisedButton ref={(button) => { this.RaisedButtonMonth = button; }} label="Primary" value = "month" onTouchTap={()=>this.buttonPress( this.RaisedButtonMonth )}  primary={true} />
<RaisedButton ref={(button) => { this.RaisedButtonYear = button; }} label="Primary" value = "year" onTouchTap={()=>this.buttonPress( this.RaisedButtonYear )}  primary={true} />
```

---

On a side note, what you are passing into `buttonPress` is not an event object, but rather a reference to the button itself.

Comment: would you show me how to get the event object for `RaisedButton`. I tried ,but I couldn't succeed .That's why I had to use ref.